# Stack frame memory allocation

Tags: c, stack

Like every function is put on a stack frame for its execution and it is flushed after its completion. So, any local variable wont be available to other functions. But then how are we able to return a local variable to the caller?

```
int pickMin( int x, int y, int z ) {
 int min = x ;
 if ( y < min )
    min = y ;
 if ( z < min )
    min = z ;
 return min ;   }
```

The above code works fine. However the in the below code, compiler does give a warning message- "`warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr] return a;` " but it prints a garbage value at the end, which I think is fine because the variable has already been flushed. But why didn't that happen in the ABOVE program?! I mean, it should also have returned me a garbage value.Moreover, I know that the problem in the below code can be solved using `malloc`, and  then returning that value. :)

```
int *returnarray(){
 int a[10]; int i;
  for(i=0;i<10;++i){
     a[i] = i;
 }return a;}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C passes everything around by value. In your first snippet, `return min` returns an `int` variable. Its value is returned. The second snippet consists of `return` and an array name, which decays into a pointer.
The *value* that is returned, is the memory address of a *local variable*. The function where this variable existed has returned, though, and accessing the memory that this function used then invokes undefined behaviour.

The way to handle this kind of situation (ie: needing to return an array) is either by passing the target array to the function as an argument, or by allocating the memory using `malloc` and returning that pointer.
Heap memory is a tad slower, more error prone, and requires you to look after it though. Still, [here's an example of both approaches](https://eval.in/187209)
`create_fill` allocates, assigns and returns a pointer to the heap memory, `fill_array` doesn't return anything, but expects you to pass an array (which decays into a pointer), and a max length to fill. The advantage being: stack memory doesn't require as much care, and will outperform the heap.

Answer (score 3):

The `return` statement des exactly that: it copies the value of a variable, and leaves it on top of the stack so the calling function can use it. Now, in C this works for simple values, not for arrays because your "array variable" `a` is actually the address of its first value only.

Answer (score 3):

First, read carefully [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) wikipage. There are nice pictures on it. See also the [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) wikipage.

Then, the result (of some C function) often goes thru a register when returned (or, for large `struct`-s, in a stack space allocated by the caller).

Details are [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific. For Linux on x86-64 (in 64 bits), the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) mentions the `%rax` register to return a result (in common cases, but when the result is a large `struct` the caller passes an address for it).

BTW, in principle, I believe that nothing in the C99 standard *requires* a stack, but I know no C implementations without a call stack (generally the processor stack, i.e. thru the [stack register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_register)).

Answer (score 0):

In first case you return value of a variable.

While, in second case you return address of a local variable which as you correctly said is not available for other functions. In C, the name of an array is the base address of that array. Hence in second case, "base address of array" is copied to any variable/pointer, which is assigned the return value of that function